# Importing SVG as React component returns an error

Tags: reactjs, svg, frontend, vite

I have a React app bootstrapped with Vite, tried to import a dark mode feature which contains two svg files but I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: 
The requested module '/src/Components/DarkMode/Moon.svg?import' does not provide an export named 'ReactComponent' (at DarkMode.jsx:5:10)
```

The component file where I'm making the imports:

```
import React from "react";
import "./DarkMode.css";
import { ReactComponent as Sun } from "./Sun.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Moon } from "./Moon.svg";

const DarkMode = () => {
return (
    <div className='dark_mode'>
        <input
            className='dark_mode_input'
            type='checkbox'
            id='darkmode-toggle'
        />
        <label className='dark_mode_label' htmlFor='darkmode-toggle'>
            <Sun />
            <Moon />
        </label>
    </div>
 );
};

export default DarkMode;`
```

My `vite.config.js` file:

```
   import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
   import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react' 
   import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr'

   // https://vitejs.dev/config/
   export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react(), svgr()],
   })
```

What could be the issue please?

Comment: According to the readme, the import syntax for svg components should be `import Logo from "./logo.svg?react"`

Comment: i tried that method too..but not working i think there is a version mismatch of the vite-plugin-svgr

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you should add more details to provide clarifications. what does your folder structure look like? `package.json` file? the paths to the SVGs may also have an error, etc